# Using Google Analytics for android, redirected to firebase?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I'm trying to add Google Analytics(GA) into my android project. But I couldn't find where to generate a google-services.json file. (I did generate it in another project before, but it seems that Google remove the link in [guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).)

Comment: as per updated google play service you no need to create google-services.json file.

Comment: you just need to sign up for this google analytics link : https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/?authuser=0#provision/SignUp/ and you will get the tracking id

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm handling a new project which i didn't get the json file and registered in the website......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [developer.android.com](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html) blog now google analytics service are deprecated and about to close around 11 April 2019.
And as per their document If you have implemented google analytics then migrate to firebase.
And if you are fresh to implement then try firebase.
That document provide all information about your query.

**Steps to implement firebase analytics to your app.**

1. simply implement firebase analytics just click on android studio's Tools menu.
2. Then select firebase and it show one firebase assistant in your android studio window.
3. Select firebase analytics option from them and it show the instruction how to implement it.
   That's it. It will tack around just 5 minutes.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Okay...Actually, I did find serval links in google analytics link to firebase website. Thank you.

Comment: There's no single word about analytics in that blog post, they deprecate GCM, not GA